# Replace img with div jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, replacewith

I'm looking to replace an image with a class to a div with text inside it, how can I do that?

```
<script>
$('img.vCSS_img_history_off').replaceWith('<div id="button">Turn History Off</div>');
</script>
```

I know that code is screwed up, but it's just to paint a picture of what I'm looking for, any suggestions?

Comment: What's screwed up about your code? What isn't working?

Comment: Don't forget to wrap this in `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ /* here*/ });`

Comment: @Pierre Wait, you mean this? `$(function () { /* here */ });`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Yep, but the "longer" version is easier for newbies to understand.

Comment: @Pierre Using the longer form just because it's easier to understand is a recipe for a lousy programmer. Have more faith in beginners. I'm sure they can figure out the shorter form without trouble.

Comment: Holy cow you're right, all I had to do was call it on the page load! I wrote this myself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the DOM is ready before you go searching for elements in it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img.vCSS_img_history_off').replaceWith('<div id="button">Turn History Off</div>');
});
```

Alternatively, you can add whatever you need to after the image and then remove it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").after("<div>Inserted div</div>").remove();
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/uACTx/1/).

More on `.after()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/after/) and more on `.remove()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to use this but it will erase other parent's child (as @Vide Simas said):

```
$(".myImage").parent().html('<div>hello</div>');
```

What you wrote looks like good, i've written a jsfiddle using `replaceWidth`: http://jsfiddle.net/ydZg5/

The error must be somewhere else

Comment: Images are empty elements, you cannot put a DIV inside an image.

Comment: That only works for images that are only childs (since all children of the parent are removed).

Answer (score 0):

The code below will replace an image with class name "myImageClassName" with a div containing the text "This is my div text":

```
$('img.myImageClassName').replaceWith('<div>This is my div text</div>');
```

but yeah, I gotta agree with the others.. your code looks fine.

Comment: Re-writing the question is not considered as an answer. Anyway, the solution was wrote down in the question comments 5min ago.